# Writing a PHP query parser with regular expressions

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm trying to write the correct regular expression in PHP to parse a string (written by some user) to build a request. It can be as complex as :

```
name = 'benjo' and (surname = 'benny' or surname = 'bennie') or age = 4
```

Later I'll parse the string to build mySQL queries. For now, I'm just trying to find the correct regular expression to parse this string into an array that could look like :

```
$result = array(
0 => name = 'benjo',
1 => and
2 => array(
    0 => surname = 'benny',
    1 => or,
    2 => surname = 'bennie',
    ),
3 => age = 4
);
```

I've thought about using recursive functions, and my regular expression for now is :

```
"#\((([^()]+|(?R))*)\)|(ou[^()])|(et[^()])#",
```

which of course does not work.

I'll be glad if someone could help, I'm getting kinda stuck here ! :)
Tks,
Romain

LET'S CHANGE THE CHALLENGE ! :)
OK, now let's make it a bit more simple. What would it take with a regular expression and adding the constraint that we stay on "level one" !! No nested parenthesis, just one level, but still as many AND/ORs... Would that change anything in favor or REGEXPs ? (I really would like to avoid writing my mini parser although that sounds really interesting...

Comment: what's the source of the original string?

Comment: It is an input ! (ps: i don't want to check input for bad code or injection at this stage!) ;)

Comment: You're probably better off making a little mini-parser of your own rather than using regular expressions.

Comment: Ok Corbin, but how can I build a mini parser without using regexp ?? I need to capture recursively what' both IN the parentesis, and the 'and' and 'or's ...

Comment: Search for 'php recursive descent parser' - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769

Comment: @Romain Bruckert: it can be done using any [FSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) implementation or (more difficult but more robust) writing [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)

Comment: @zerkms With an FSM you’re back to regular expressions. This is inadequate here.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: FSM allows you to choose how to parse. And even with regexes - FSM is easier (from maintaining point of view) solution than just plain regexes, just because it is FSM

Comment: @zerkms I don’t know what you mean. FSMs are perfectly expressed by regular expressions. Why would manually writing an FSM here help? How is that easier to maintain (it isn’t – changes in specs incur much larger changes in code). I think you are confusing them with a recursive descent parser.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: just because regular expressions are for regular languages, while FSMs can parse literally anything?

Comment: @zerkms No, you are simply confusing things. FSM and regex are the same thing.

Comment: Wooo thanks to you all, now can't make my choice. I think I'll use some fixed pattern. the user will click on a radio button AND/OR to add his criterias and i'll force other inputs to build the request ! Isn't that the best solution ? ;)

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: regex is one of the possible datasources for FSM. I cannot get how "screw" can be the same thing as "car". PS: found this http://qntm.org/algo --- now I understand what you mean, but still don't agree that they are **the same thing**. They **may** express the same parse logic, but it doesn't make regex equal to FSM

Comment: @zerkms Mathematically speaking, they are the same, just two different *representations*. I used the “same thing” shortcut since you didn’t seem to understand that FSMs aren’t more powerful than regular expressions.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: ok, seems like I just don't have enough math background for this discussion, sorry ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretical regular expression is not powerful enough to do parentheses matching. Theoretical regular expression can only take care of left recursion/right recursion rules. Middle recursion rules is cannot be expressed with regular expression (e.g. `<exp> -> "(" <exp> ")"`).

Regex in programming languages, however, implements features which allow regex to exceed the power of regular grammar. For example, backreference in regex allows one to write a regex which matches [a non context-free languages](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/where-do-most-regex-implementations-fall-on-the-complexity-scale). However, even with backreference, it's still not possible to balance parentheses with regex.

As PCRE library supports recursive regex via *subroutine call* feature, it is technically possible to parse such an expression with regex. However, **unless you can write the regex yourself**, which means that you understand what you are doing and can modify the regex to suit your needs, **you should just write your own parser**. Otherwise, you will end up with an unmaintainable mess.

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<string>'[^']++')
  (?<int>\b\d+\b)
  (?<sp>\s*)
  (?<key>\b\w+\b)
  (?<value>(?&string)|(?&int))
  (?<exp>(?&key) (?&sp) = (?&sp) (?&value))
  (?<logic>\b (?:and|or) \b)
  (?<main>
    (?<token> \( (?&sp) (?&main) (?&sp) \) | (?&exp) )
    (?:
      (?&sp) (?&logic) (?&sp)
      (?&token) 
    )*
  )
)
(?:
  ^ (?&sp) (?= (?&main) (?&sp) $ )
  |
  (?!^) \G
  (?&sp) (?&logic) (?&sp)
)
(?:
  \( (?&sp) (?<m_main>(?&main)) (?&sp) \)
  |
  (?<m_key>(?&key)) (?&sp) = (?&sp) (?<m_value>(?&value))
)
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/xC2wK3/3)

The regex above should be use with `preg_match_all`, and placed between delimiter with x flag (free spacing mode): `/.../x`.

For each match:

- If `m_main` capturing group has content, put the content through another round of matching.
- Otherwise, get the key and value in `m_key` and `m_value` capturing group.

### Explanation

The `(?(DEFINE)...)` block allows you to define named capturing groups for use in subroutine calls separately from the main pattern.

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<string>'[^']++')  # String literal
  (?<int>\b\d+\b)      # Integer
  (?<sp>\s*)           # Whitespaces between tokens
  (?<key>\b\w+\b)      # Field name
  (?<value>(?&string)|(?&int)) # Field value
  (?<exp>(?&key) (?&sp) = (?&sp) (?&value)) # Simple expression
  (?<logic>\b (?:and|or) \b) # Logical operators
  (?<main>             # <token> ( <logic> <token> )*
    # A token can contain a simple expression, or open a parentheses (...)
    # When we open a parentheses, we recurse into the main pattern again
    (?<token> \( (?&sp) (?&main) (?&sp) \) | (?&exp) )
    (?:
      (?&sp) (?&logic) (?&sp)
      (?&token) 
    )*
  )
)
```

The rest of the pattern is [based on this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268504/collapse-and-capture-a-repeating-pattern-in-a-single-regex-expression/15418942#15418942) to match all `<token>`s in `<token> ( <logic> <token> )*` with global matching operation.

The last part of the regex, while can be written as `(?&token)`, is expanded to match the field name and value in the simple expressions.

```
(?:
  \( (?&sp) (?<m_main>(?&main)) (?&sp) \)
  |
  (?<m_key>(?&key)) (?&sp) = (?&sp) (?<m_value>(?&value))
)
```

Comment: Actually, PHP’s “regular” expressions *can* do parenthesis matching, and I think it might even parse OP’s expression but the result would be an arcane, unmaintainable mess.

Comment: Just curious, but can you show how you would check whether the parentheses are matched correctly in this case: `([()[()][[((()))]]])` with PHP regex?

Comment: @nhahtdh: there is even an example of doing that in PHP's manual (hint: recursive regexes)

Comment: Yes i got that from the manual, but i don't think it works for nested parentesis.

Comment: @Romain Bruckert: it does - that is what *recursive* about