# How to build advance query builder in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, query-builder

I want to create advance query builder using PHP code.

Input :

`search_String_1 AND( search_String_2 OR search_String_3)` ... so on

Goal :

check AND / OR operator rules including () parenthesis and convert it into following String:
Query :

```
db.table.search_field LIKE '
search_String_1' AND ( db.table.search_field LIKE 'search_String_2' OR db.table.search_field LIKE 'search_String_3')'
```

My efforts:

I have use `preg_match()` but I dont know how to check all operator and query sequences by best solution. Also I have exploded user input by "`blank_space`" , so i have all token in one array. I am still trying to  find solution. If I am wrong or there is a good solution  please suggest me to do so.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can we see some of your not so advanced attempts at it and build upon them?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772561/writing-a-php-query-parser-with-regular-expressions

Comment: I recently had the same need to parse a query string as you've described into an SQL statement. It is possible in regex, but I don't recommend it, as it will be very unwieldy and not flexible. I wrote a parser that goes through the string character by character, parsing expressions as it goes. Try doing a search for `php expression parser`. You might need to 'roll your own', but there may be some source code available to get you started.

Comment: @AaronBlenkush I have visited [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772561/writing-a-php-query-parser-with-regular-expressions) but in my case user only input search string. Yeah I agree that I need to find character by character and check for expression. But you know I have to match all rules that SQL query parser do. e.g. There must be not more than one same operator use consecutive  unless there are separated by '(' or ')' etc , so there will be more string traversal would be needed.

Comment: Define your operator rules. Mine was similar to something you'd type into the Criteria box in Microsoft Access. For example, the user might type in `="Green" OR "Black"` and my parser would output `Field = "Green" OR Field = "Black"`. You're exactly right - you can't have more than one operator in a row. So `= = "Red"` is invalid. My parser has a variable that keeps track of the next "expected" token. First expects an operator, then an expression, then either end of string or a connector (AND, OR, XOR, etc). If at any point the parser comes across an unexpected token it throws an error.

Comment: @AaronBlenkush Okay, There is not unique Operator that my query builder is going to support. I can give you one example of user inputted String. 


`document AND collaboration` OR `(file OR document) AND collaboration`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this class. It may be usefull.

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/12314.html

Comment: Thanks for suggest. I have looked the code that you have suggested but there must be `WHERE` clause I need to provided by my own. And my question is how to create that `WHERE` clause based upon the user's `inputted String`.