# Regex: Find groups of lowercase letters between HTML tag

Tags: html, regex, epub

I'm attempting to develop a regular expression that can be run in [Sigil](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/), the ePub 2 editor.

Small-caps are a well-known problem within the current ePub reader ecosystem. Many readers, such as Adobe Digital Editions, do not support "font-variant: small-caps". After trying several different workarounds, I've settled on creating fake small caps by transforming the text to uppercase and setting the previously lowercase letters to "font-size: 0.75em".

This process is extremely tedious, especially when working with books that have lots of endnotes with citations of other books.

Say that I have a bunch of phrases in an HTML page tagged with an "SC" class. I've created a test phrase:

```
<span class="SC">Hello World! Testing: one tWo thrEE &amp; W.T.F.</span>
<span class="foo">Don't touch me!</span>
```

The goal is to write a regex that matches any lowercase letters within the "SC" span tag only, and replace them with:

```
<span class="FSC">LETTERS</span>
```

I can manage to match and replace the letters in the first word "Hello", but everything breaks down after that.

Here's what I've got so far:

**Find:**

```
(<span class="SC">.*?)([a-z]+)(.*</span>)
```

**Replace:**

```
\1<span class="FSC">\U\2\E</span>\3
```

The tricky part is then continuing to find the rest of the lowercase letters within that tag, now that a new "FSC" (Fake Small Caps) span tag has been introduced. Trying the same regex again results in "span" and then "class" getting the *FSC* treatment. Ideally, I'd like to be able to just keep hitting the "Replace All" button until no more matches are found.

The above example would look like this when finished:

```
<span class="SC">H<span class="FSC">ELLO</span> W<span class="FSC">ORLD</span>! T<span class="FSC">ESTING</span>: <span class="FSC">ONE</span> <span class="FSC">T</span>W<span class="FSC">O</span> <span class="FSC">THR</span>EE &amp; W.T.F.</span>
<span class="foo">Don't touch me!</span>
```

It's not pretty, but it works on every ePub reader that I've tested it on.

If you google "epub small caps regex", you'll come across a MobileRead wiki article that I edited to include this regex, which I've decided is not satisfactory:

```
(<span class="[a-zA-Z0-9\- ]*?(?<!F)SC[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*?">(?:.+?<span class="FSC">.+?</span>)*[\.|,|:|;|-|–|—|!|\?]? ?(?:&amp;)? ?[A-Z]+)([a-z'’\. ]+)(.*?</span>)
```

This ends up miniaturizing a bunch of punctuation and sometimes stops in the middle of a phrase. I started over, thinking there was probably a better solution that doesn't attempt to plan for every single possibility up front.

If someone comes up with a better solution to this, you'll be the hero of the entire ePub publishing industry.

### Update

I've added the accepted (and only) answer to the [Mobile Read wiki](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/EPubHacks). Please note that this regex has been altered specifically for use in Sigil; YMMV in other environments.

Comment: It's 2013. Don't try to parse HTML with regexes.

Comment: Sigil doesn't have scripting support, otherwise I'd try something else. I'm trying to find a solution that most people would be able to use by copy/pasting from a wiki page.

Comment: Just feed the text into a scripting language of your choice that has an XML parsing library (eg Python, Perl, Ruby, etc).

Comment: @JackManey RegEx is not what it started out anymore, it can be used for much more than parse 'regular languages', for more info read [NikiC's blog post](http://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: @JackManey I admit that's probably a better approach, and I'll be heading that way if I don't receive any helpful responses here. Still, I don't believe that this has as much to do with "parsing" as the question you (presumably) marked as answering this one. I'm simply trying to _match_ some lowercase letters here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perfect usecase for: [Collapse and Capture a Repeating Pattern in a Single Regex Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268504/collapse-and-capture-a-repeating-pattern-in-a-single-regex-expression)

Modified it for your case:

```
(<span class="SC">(?:(?!<\/span>)(?:[^a-z&]|&[^;]+;))*|(?!^)\G(?:(?!<\/span>)(?:[^a-z&]|&[^;]+;))*)([a-z]+)
```

Replace with: `\1<span class="FSC">\U\2\E</span>`

And here's the RegEx explained: http://regex101.com/r/jU6bA5

This is a solution for "**Replace All**" as it works via RegEx global modifier `/g` !