# Regex: Recursively remove surrounding <div> tags in HTML

Tags: html, regex, xhtml, epub, adobe-indesign

Before someone whines about not using regex to parse HTML, I refer you to a previous question of mine with an elegant solution which was quickly labeled as "answered" by another question's answer whining about not using regex to parse HTML (which was eventually removed from my question): [Regex: Find groups of lowercase letters between HTML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957420/regex-find-groups-of-lowercase-letters-between-html-tag)

I am again working with epubs (in [Sigil](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/)), this time cleaning up the XHTML output from InDesign CC. Different from previous ID versions, it now surrounds many objects with extra `<div>` tags for some kind of positioning/layout reason. I am writing my own clean CSS, so the epub is exported without generating CSS, leaving extraneous `<div>` tags surrounding other `<div>`s, sometimes containing a *nested structure* of unnecessary `<div>`s.

An example of what I'm dealing with:

```html
<div><!--unnecessary-->
    <div class="figure-box">
        <h4 class="f-n"><b class="b">Figure 1.3: Foobar</b></h4>
        <div><!--unnecessary-->
            <div class="figure">
                <img alt="foo" src="../Images/bar.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="f-ct">This is a caption, yadda yadda.</p>
        <p class="f-src">Source: Copyright blah blah.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: `<!--unnecessary-->` comments are illustrative, and are not present in the actual code.

I have written this regular expression in an attempt to remove the unstyled surrounding `<div>` tags with some success, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution:

```
^(\s*)<div>\n\s*(<div class=".+?">.+?</div>)\n\1</div>
```

The above string matches the outermost `<div>`, where I can then do a replace with `\1\2` to keep the contents and also the first indent (though the indent isn't absolutely necessary).

The issue with this is that I must do a **find/replace all** several times in order to get at and remove all of the unnecessary `<div>`s that are nested.

Is this as good as it will get, or is there a solution like the one I linked to above for this purpose?

Comment: Repeatedly replacing is fine.

Comment: +1 just for self promoting your own previous solution with the word "elegant"

Comment: [This is for everybody who is interested in some elegant whining.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @Phlume Hey, I didn't come up with it. I'd been led to believe stuff like that wouldn't work because of the general sentiment here on SO (as allcaps was quick to confirm), and yet someone helped me out. Maybe it's presumptuous to call it "elegant", but it answered the question.

Comment: I just thought it was funny you used elegant for code. no harm.

Comment: I don't think you can improve by only using regexp. I would recommend a more HTML-structure aware approach, but as long as you have a perfectly formated source-code your solution should do. With a loop that loops until no further matches are found.

Comment: [All things are possible, but not all expedient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272).