# Regular expression to get selected columns

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have to extract column names from a MYSQL `SELECT` and I'd wish to do that using Regex.
It's a plain `SELECT`, something like:
`SELECT column1, column2 ... FROM table`

I have to cover every cases, with our without alias, with or without table in front of it, with or without the quoting char:

```
SELECT column, column as foo, table.column, table.column as foo, 
       `column`, `column` as foo, `table`.`column`, `table`.`column` as foo
       .....
```

Currently I've been able to work out this regex: `#\w+(\sas)?#i` but it's not good vs prefixed columns.
Any help?

By the way, is Regex good at this task?

**EDIT**
Thanks for the answers!
The patterns you posted are valid for the whole query, actually I'm already processing every single column:

```
$fields = Frameworkmethod::getSelectFields($query);
$columns = explode(',' , $fields);
foreach($columns as $column)
{
     //do Regex work to "clean up" the single field and get the "standard" one (not the alias)
     //`#__tracktime_projects`.`pr_name` AS `project_name` should return pr_name
}
```

As stated in the comment above, I always need the field name, not the alias one.
Sorry for not pointing it out before!

Comment: `is Regex good at this task` that totally depends on the language you are using to program!Specify the language/tool you are using so that we can help you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made use of [Collapse and Capture a Repeating Pattern in a Single Regex Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15268504/731947) and adapted it to fit this purpose.

So, a *hopefully bulletproof* RegEx for capturing column names from a ***SQL** query :

```
/(?:SELECT\s++(?=(?:[#\w,`.]++\s++)+)|(?!^)\G\s*+,\s*+(?:`?+\s*+[#\w]++\s*+`?+\s*+\.\s*+)?+`?+\s*+)(\w++)`?+(?:\s++as\s++[^,\s]++)?+/ig
```

Explained Online demo: http://regex101.com/r/wL7yA9

PHP code using preg_match_all() with single RegEx, commented with `/x` modifier:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:SELECT\s++(?=(?:[\#\w,`.]++\s++)+) # start matching on SELECT
                |              # or
                (?!^)\G        # resume from last match position 
                \s*+,\s*+      # delimited by a comma 
                (?:`?+\s*+     # optional prefix table with optional backtick
                    [\#\w]++   # table name
                    \s*+`?+    # optional backtick
                    \s*+\.\s*+ # dot separator
                )?+ # optional prefix table end group

                `?+\s*+ # optional backtick

            ) # initial match or subsequent match

            (\w++)    # capturing group
            `?+         # optional backtick


            (?:\s++as\s++[^,\s]++)?+ # optional alias

            /ix', $query, $matches);
```

Live code: http://codepad.viper-7.com/VTaPd3

*Note: the 'hopefully bulletproof' is aimed at valid SQL*

---

PHP code using explode()

```
$columns = explode(',', $fields);

foreach($columns as $column)
{
    $regex='/([\w]++)`?+(?:\s++as\s++[^,\s]++)?+\s*+(?:FROM\s*+|$)/i';

    preg_match($regex, $column, $match);

    print $match[1]; // field stored in $match[1]
}
```

Live code with example extraction: http://codepad.viper-7.com/OdUGXd

Answer (score 2):

I used PHP:

```
$query = 'SELECT column1, column2 as foo, table.column3, table.column4 as foo, 
       `column5`, `column6` as foo, `table`.`column7`, `table`.`column8` as foo
       FROM table';

$query = preg_replace('/^SELECT(.*?)FROM.*$/s', '$1', $query); // To remove the "SELECT" and "FROM table..." parts

preg_match_all('/(?:
    (?:`?\w+`?\.)? (?:`)?(\w+)(?:`)? (?:\s*as\s*\w+)?\s*
#   ^--TableName-^ ^---ColumnName--^ ^----AsFoo-----^
)+/x',$query, $m);

print_r($m[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => column1
    [1] => column2
    [2] => column3
    [3] => column4
    [4] => column5
    [5] => column6
    [6] => column7
    [7] => column8
)
```

Live demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/H960NFKCTr

---

**UPDATE:** Since you're using some "unusual" but valid SQL table names (e.g.: `#__tracktime_projects`) it has messed up the regex. So to fix this issue, I added a variable which contains what characters we would expect, I also added the `i` modifier to make the match caseless:

```
$query = 'SELECT column1, column2 as foo, table.column3, table.column4 as foo, 
       `column5`, `column6` as foo, `table`.`column7`, `table`.`column8` as foo, `#__tracktime_projects`.`pr_name` AS project_name, `#wut`
       FROM table';


$query = preg_replace('/^SELECT(.*?)FROM.*$/s', '$1', $query); // To remove the "SELECT" and "FROM table..." parts

$allowed = '\w#'; // Adjust this to the names that you expect.

preg_match_all('/(?:
    (?:`?['.$allowed.']++`?\.)?
#   ^--------TableName--------^

    (?:`)?(['.$allowed.']++)(?:`)?
#   ^----------ColumnName--------^

    (?:\s*as\s*['.$allowed.']++)?\s*
#   ^-------------AsFoo------------^
)+
/xi',$query, $m);

print_r($m[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => column1
    [1] => column2
    [2] => column3
    [3] => column4
    [4] => column5
    [5] => column6
    [6] => column7
    [7] => column8
    [8] => pr_name
    [9] => #wut
)
```

Live demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/D0iIHJQwB8

Comment: that's very nice, however I need the field name and not the alias one (sorry I just updated the question)

Comment: testing vs this string extracts the alias and not the column name: http://www.rubular.com/r/SJLbVC0GGR

Answer (score 0):

If using PHP (i'm sure other languages support this too) you could consider [`getcolumnmeta`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php). From the docs:

```
<?php
  $select = $DB->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruit');
  $meta = $select->getColumnMeta(0);
  var_dump($meta);
?>
```

Result:

```
array(6) {
  ["native_type"]=>
   string(7) "integer"
  ["flags"]=>
   array(0) {
  }
  ["name"]=>
   string(8) "COUNT(*)"
  ["len"]=>
    int(-1)
  ["precision"]=>
    int(0)
  ["pdo_type"]=>
    int(2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is generic solution:

```
((select|,)\s+((((`)?\w+\6?\.)?(`)?\w+\7?)(\s+as\s+(`)?\w+\9?)?\s*))+from\s
```

Group $3 contains column with possible table and alias decoration.

You can use non-capture groups - (?...) for some parts of expression. In such case change backreference numbers.

Run it with single line and ignore case flags. Maybe you should change identifier specification \w+ to more specific [a-zA-Z]\w* for example.

Comment: It seems that the tool reports only the last capture.

Comment: In your validator use only '(select|,)\s*(((`)?\w+\4?\.)?(`)?\w+\5?(\s+as\s+(`)?\w+\7?)?)\s*' but with isg options.

Comment: Not so great. Look at regex101.com/r/rL1bE2. Do you think that result is correct? It should list all 'a,', 'b,' and 'c,'. It's the reason why it doesn't list all columns in my regex.

Comment: let's continue this discussion on the [RegEx chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex) to avoid cluttering the comment space, also please delete the comments here

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I had the same issue and could no solve using @CSᵠ regex.
I created another regex to do the task on a wider range of columns, included calculated fields

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=^SELECT |, |\) )([a-z]+\.)?([a-z]+ )?(as )?([a-z]+)(?= ?,|$)/im');
```

If will be used in complex queries I suggest use the complete function I created: https://gist.github.com/pedrosancao/2498ed85b3c1834c5bdd

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but most of these were too complex for me and PHP-specific, which I guess is what you were after but a lot of people looking at this may not be.
The PCRE-flavored regex I went with was:

```
([\w`]+)(?=\s*,|\s+from\s+)
```

This matches alphanumeric and backticks ([\w`]+) characters that are immediately followed by a comma (or whitespace and comma) or a space and the keyword 'from'.

The latter is accomplished using a positive lookahead

```
(?=<expression>)
```

in this case

```
(?=\s*,|\s+from\s+)
```

which checks that the preceding token [\w`]+ is followed by

```
\s*,       # whitespace (0 or more) and comma
```

OR (|)

```
\s+from\s+ # the keyword 'from', surrounded by >=1 whitespace characters
```

Then you can use the case flag in whatever language flavor to ignore case.

EDIT: Should also note this matches the alias name rather than the original column name.