# how to capture every single match of a repeated pattern?

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, non-greedy

I have the following regexp:

```
/xxx ([a-z]+)(?:, ([a-z]+))* xxx/
```

I want to capture all colors in the following test string:

```
xxx red, blue, pink, purple xxx
```

(now only red and purple get captured)

open this url and see the matched groups:  http://www.regex101.com/r/oZ2cH4

I have read the following http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html but the trick didn't work

(or maybe I did it wrong)

how can I resolve this?

thank you in advance

Comment: Match against `/xxx ([a-z]+(?:, [a-z]+)*) xxx/`, take the first capturing group, then split on `, `

Comment: This answer demonstrate the idea http://stackoverflow.com/a/15922245/1400768. The other way with regex alone is very monstrous and I wouldn't recommend it - it is only for educational purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15418942/1400768

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to return a matching group based on a previous pattern matches:

```
$word = '[a-z]+';
$sep  = '[, ]+';

$words = $captures("~($word)(?:{$sep})?~");
$of    = $captures("~xxx ({$word}(?:{$sep}{$word})*) xxx~");

print_r($words($of($subject)));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
    [2] => pink
    [3] => purple
)
```

Whereas `$captures` is a function that return a pre-configured `preg_match_all` call allowing to process not only a string as subject but anything `foreach` can operate on:

```
$captures = function ($pattern, $group = 1) {
    return function ($subject) use ($pattern, $group) {
        if (is_string($subject)) {
            $subject = (array)$subject;
        }
        $captures = [];
        foreach ($subject as $step) {
            preg_match_all($pattern, $step, $matches);
            $captures = array_merge($captures, $matches[$group]);
        }
        return $captures;
    };
};
```

By default and as used in the example above, it returns the first group (1), but this can be configured.

This allows to first match the outer pattern (`$of`) and then on each of those matches the inner pattern (`$words`). The example in full:

```
$subject = '/xxx red, blue, pink, purple xxx/';

$captures = function ($pattern, $group = 1) {
    return function ($subject) use ($pattern, $group) {
        if (is_string($subject)) {
            $subject = (array)$subject;
        }
        $captures = [];
        foreach ($subject as $step) {
            preg_match_all($pattern, $step, $matches);
            $captures = array_merge($captures, $matches[$group]);
        }
        return $captures;
    };
};

$word = '[a-z]+';
$sep  = '[, ]+';
$seq  = "";

$words = $captures("~($word)(?:{$sep})?~");
$of    = $captures("~xxx ({$word}(?:{$sep}{$word})*) xxx~");

print_r($words($of($subject)));
```

See the [live-demo](http://eval.in/27567).

Comment: Hmm, interesting. You create a high-order function to process the array of strings/string.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial [*"Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group" (by regular-expressions.info)*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) describes how you would capture all of the content "red, blue, pink, purple" in a single capture.  The pattern it would suggest is

> `/xxx ((?:[a-z]+(?:, )?)+) xxx/`

but if this were really what you were trying to accomplish, you may as well use the simpler expression

> `/xxx ([a-z, ]*) xxx/`

I suspect what you actually want is to capture each color individually.  This might be best accomplished by capturing the entire list once, then parsing that captured content.

Comment: It is a bad idea to repeat the separator along with the tokens `/xxx ((?:[a-z]+(?:, )?)+) xxx/`. If you are not careful (like in this case), you will induce backtracking hell on invalid input: http://www.regex101.com/r/bS5mG3