# preg_replace replace all occurrences inside patten

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a way to replace all the occurrences of specific word inside a pattern:
for example:
`I love my dog <a>the dog is a good dog, -dog and dog: also should be converted</a>` with
`I love my dog <a>the pig is a good pig, -pig and pig: also should be converted</a>`

all the occurrences of dog inside the `<a>` tag should be replaced with pig.

I had tied the next preg_replece:
`preg_replace("/<a>.*(dog).*</a>/", "pig", $input_lines);`
but I got empty string..

I would thankful for some help.

Comment: You should either use another regex delimiter like `$` or escape the one you are using isnide `</a>` because its breaking your regex,

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$s = <<< EOF
I am looking for a way to replace all the occurrences of specific word dog inside a pattern: for example:
I love my dog <a>the dog is a good dog, -dog and dog: also should be converted</a> with
I love my dog <a>the pig is a good pig, -pig and pig: also should be converted</a>
not this dog.
EOF;
echo preg_replace_callback("~(<a>.*?</a>)~", function ($m) {
               return str_replace('dog', 'pig', $m[1]); }, $s);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
I am looking for a way to replace all the occurrences of specific word dog inside a pattern: for example:
I love my dog <a>the pig is a good pig, -pig and pig: also should be converted</a> with
I love my dog <a>the pig is a good pig, -pig and pig: also should be converted</a>
not this dog.
```

Comment: thanks, but you had lost the <a></a> tags in the process, How do I keep them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a substitution with `$1pig` using this regex:

```
((?:<a>|\G(?<!^))(.*?))\bdog\b(?=.*?<\/a>)
```

[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jE7nF9)

For a full explanation, please check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15418942/1519058) (I couldnt do better)