# Match Strings with Variable Left/Right Delimiters

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match, pcre

The problem is quite easy. I would like to match anything between some strings at the beginning and some strings at the end. **Strings at the end should match appropriate strings at the beginning**.

Let's assume that I want to match everything that is between `[` and `]` or `{` and `}`.

The first regular expression that could be used is:

`/[{\[](.*)[}\]]/gmU`

however there is one problem with it. When subject is:

`{aa} werirweiu [ab] wrewre [ac}`

also `[ac}` is matched but it shouldn't.

It can be easily changed into:

`/\[(.*)\]|\{(.*)\}/gmU`

and the problem is solved.

But what in case if  `(.*)` were much more complicated and beginnings and ends would be for example 10 and they also would be a bit more complicated (not one character but many)? Then using above rule the whole `(.*)` should be repeated 10 times and it would be illegible.

Is there any way to match ends with beginnings? For example I would like to use syntax similar to

`/(aa|bb)(.*)(cc|ddd)/gmU` to tell that match must begin with `aa` and ends with `cc` or begin with `bb` and ends with `ddd` and match in subject `aaxx1cc bbxx2ddd aaxx3ddd bbxx4cc` only strings `xx1` and `xx2` without repeating `(.*)` many times in that regular expression and remembering there might be more than 2 as in above examples beginnings and endings.

Comment: Instead of using `.*` use something else

Comment: might help to read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15268504/731947

Comment: Or join the cool kids and start reading from [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17902539#17902539).

Comment: No possibility of nesting? E.g. `{a{a}a} werirweiu [a{a}b] wrewre [a{b[cd]a}c]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Use a Conditional

In my view, this is a very nice place to use conditionals. This regex will work:

```
(?:(\[)|({)).*?(?(1)\])(?(2)})
```

See what matches and fails in [**the Regex Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eC5uK2/4).

**Other Kinds of Delimiters**

This is easy to expand: for instance, the following pattern will match strings delimited between `START` and `END`, or between  `<--` and `-->`, or between `==:` and `:==`

```
(?:(START)|(<--)|(==:)).*?(?(1)END)(?(2)-->)(?(3):==)
```

See the **[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eC5uK2/7)**.

**Explanation**

- The non-capture group `(?:(\[)|({))` matches the opening delimiter, i.e. either
- `[` which `(\[)` captures to Group 1
- OR `|`
- `{` which `({)` captures to Group 2
- `.*?` lazily matches up to a point where...
- `(?(1)\])` if Group 1 is set, we match `]`
- `(?(2)})` if Group 2 is set, we match `}`

**Reference**

- [Conditional Regex 101](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html)
- [If-Then-Else Conditionals in Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)