# selecting named group in regex, when multiple matches

Tags: java, regex

I have written below regex

```
  "(?<customer>(\\w)+)" // to match c1 
        + "\\(((,)*" // To match (
        + "(?<product>(\\w)+),(?<likeness>(\\d)+)+)+" // to match p2,4
        + "\\)"; // To  match )
```

For below input:

```
C1(P2,51,P4,13)
```

Now Problem is when I execute

```
matcher.group("product");
```

It gives me p4, is there any way, I can get first p2 and then p4.

Comment: It is because the capture group will contain the last match which is `p4`

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6020436/1025201)

Comment: Each capture group in your regex will return one substring.  You cannot use capture groups to return multiple substrings from the source, even if the group is inside a pattern with `*` or `+`.  regexes just aren't set up to do that.  Sorry.

Comment: You can capture the whole thing inside the bracket and do a second pass on the data (by splitting or matching - up to you). There is the second method of rewriting your regex, but I do not recommend it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268504/collapse-and-capture-a-repeating-pattern-in-a-single-regex-expression/15418942#15418942