# How can I use Regular Expressions to parse every item from the list to a separate group?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to parse the items with a single matching using a regular expression.
I need the items to be assigned to groups individually.

`custPowerCourse := 11.1,22.2,33.3,44.4,55.5;`

Here is a proposed RegEx

`((\w+)\s)?:=(\s?("[\w\s]*"|(\d+\.\d+)*)\s?(,|;|$))+`

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: [Kind of duplicate...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268504/collapse-and-capture-a-repeating-pattern-in-a-single-regex-expression)

Comment: group(2)=11.1, group(3)=22.2, group(4)=33.3,...etc

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+))|(\w+)
```

Try this.Grab the captures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/25

Comment: thanks. I was trying to match the whole line with one scan, and use () to group the items into different groups like this group(2)=11.1, group(3) = 22.2,...etc

Comment: @ABDULLAHTRABOULSI this get you all the groups right?

Comment: yes, but at different iterations... You need to use matcher.find() to get the next item and the next one, and so on

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the results in a list, then reading from it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String txt = "11.1,22.2,33.3,44.4,55.5;";
    final String re1="([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])"; //regex to match floats
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    final List<Float> results = new ArrayList<Float>();

    while (m.find()) {
        final String float1 = m.group(0);
        results.add(Float.parseFloat(float1));
    }

    for(final Float f : results){
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: If i can not read it in a one scan...i might use this solution

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when regex start to became complex, I like to do it step by step (this time in perl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;
my $a= "custPowerCourse = 11.1,22.2,33.3,44.4,55.5;";

if( ($lhs,$rhs)= $a =~ /(\w+)\s*:=\s*(.*);/){  ## if a is lhs := rhs,         
    @g  =   $rhs =~ /([\d.]+)/g;               ## extract numbers from rhs
    print Dumper(\@g);
}
```