# Searching for multiple elements with regex

Tags: php, regex

How can I check for a variable number of elements in a string?

```
[keyword1|keyword2|keyword3]
[keyword1|keyword2]
```

... or more than three keywords. This would just work for three elements:

```
preg_match("/^\[(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\]$/",$string, $matches)
```

**Edit:** How can I get the captured keyword in variables? i.e.:

```
matches[1] = keyword1
matches[2] = keyword2
matches[3] = keyword3
```

Comment: did you want for 3 and more?

Comment: You'll need two separate patterns, one to validate the string, and one to extract the keywords.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Variable Number, that means 1 or more keyword in that string (beginning with [ and ending with ])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, 3 and more.

```
^\[[^|\n]*(?:\|[^|\n]*){2,}\]$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/27)

FOr more than 3,

```
^\[[^|\n]*(?:\|[^|\n]*){3,}]$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/28)

You could do simply like this through `\G` anchor,

```
(?:^\[|\G)\|?([^\n|\]]+)(?=[\]|])
```

Use `\G` anchor to do a continuous string match.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rF1sU7/3)

Comment: `preg_match("/^\[[^|\n]*(?:\|[^|\n]*){2,}\]$/",$string, $matches)` So my result would be: $matches[1], $matches[2], ... $matches[n]. Correct?

Comment: no, it matches that particular line only. Did you want to capture the keywords? Could you edit the question with expected output?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the unsufficient question. Updated the question.

Comment: In the regex101.com-link every second result is empty? `match1 = 'keyword 1', match2 = ''` and so on...

Comment: I think you could filter out the empty strings from an array easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
(?:^\[(?=[^][|]*(?:\|[^][|]*)*\])|(?!^)\G)([^][|]*)(?:[]|])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<kbd>[`DEMO`](https://regex101.com/r/rF1sU7/1)</kbd>

This technique is explained in details <kbd>[`HERE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15418942/1519058)</kbd>

Comment: @user3142695 It looks scary, but once you read the doc (link above) you'll see how much it's simple :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj it's true that the `(?=...)` is not needed here, it only controls how many results to grab... Removing it will give a similar pattern to yours, so I'll leave it