# Use same string part for regex inspection

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm pretty new to regex, but I did some study.
I got into a problem that might turn out impossible to be solved by regex, so I need a piece of advice.

I have the following string:

```
some text key 12, 32, 311 ,465 and 345. some other text dog 612, 
12, 32, 9 and 10. some text key 1, 2.
```

I'm trying to figure if it possible (using regex only) to extract the numbers `12` `32` `311` `465` `345` `1` `2` only - as a set of individual matches.

When I approach this problem I tried to look for a pattern that matches only the relevant results.
So I came up with :

- get numbers that have prefix of "key" and NOT have prefix of "dog".

But I'm not sure if it is even possible. I mean that I know that for the number `1` I can use `(?<=key )+[\d]+` and get it as a result, but for the rest of the numbers (i.e. `2..5`), can I "use" the `key` prefix again?

Comment: Could you try to rewrite your question? It's not clear. Do you want to extract numbers or digits? What would you like to get from 11, 51, 1dog, dog1?

Comment: Exctracting numbers. the point is to extract only numbers that are followed by `key` string and NOT by `dog` string

Comment: Are you expecting a single string match (i.e. `"12, 32, 311 ,465 and 345"`), or are you looking for a set of individual matches (i.e. `{12,32,311,465,345}`)?

Comment: I'm expecting for set of individual matches. (edited my question). thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in `2` steps.

```
(?<=key\\s)\\d+(?:\\s*(?:,|and)\\s*\\d+)*
```

Grab all the numbers.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uK9cD8/6

Then `split` or `extract \\d+` from it.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uK9cD8/7

Comment: I'm afraid two steps is not an option for me. is it possible in single step?

Comment: @GilPeretz 2 steps is a sure shot way of achieving what you want.You anyways cannot do it in a single regex with 100 % accuracy.

Comment: Initially, you were looking for a single regex to do it. I see the limitations of a constrained width lookbehind and nested lookarounds scared you off. Anyway, it's great you have solutions to choose from!

Answer (score 3):

In Java, you can make use of a constrained width look-behind that accepts `{n,m}` limiting quantifier.

So, you can use

```
(?<=key(?:(?!dog)[^.]){0,100})[0-9]+
```

Or, if `key` and `dog` are whole words, use `\b` word boundary:

```
String pattern = "(?<=\\bkey\\b(?:(?!\\bdog\\b)[^.]){0,100})[0-9]+";
```

The only problem there may arise if the distance between the `dog` or `key` and the numbers is bigger than `m`. You may increase it to 1000 and I think that would work for most cases.

Sample [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/QsGhvD)

```
String str = "some text key 12, 32, 311 ,465 and 345. some other text dog 612,\n12, 32, 9 and 10. some text key 1, 2.";
String str2 = "some text key 1, 2, 3 ,4 and 5. some other text dog 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10. some text, key 1, 2 dog 3, 4 key 5, 6";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?<=key(?:(?!dog)[^.]){0,100})[0-9]+");
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
System.out.println("-----");
m = ptrn.matcher(str2);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Comment: Assumption being made here is that dog and key does not appear in the same "sentence" (delimited by `.`).

Comment: Correct. That is what the sample input implies.

Comment: My issue with this solution is that the String: `key 1, 2 dog 3, 4 key 5, 6` will not work. I added it to the question example.

Comment: @GilPeretz: Write that test case in your question.

Comment: @nhahtdh added it. Thank you.

Comment: Note that while it's possible to use look-behind this way in Java, it's extremely inefficient, since Java implements look-behind by *trying to match* at index (current - min_look_behind_length) to (current - max_look_behind_length).

Comment: I have been noting the same everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend using code that you can't understand and customize, but here is my one-pass solution, using [the method described in this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268504/collapse-and-capture-a-repeating-pattern-in-a-single-regex-expression/15418942#15418942). If you want to understand the construction method, please read the other answer.

```
(?:key(?>\s+and\s+|[\s,]+)|(?!^)\G(?>\s+and\s+|[\s,]+))(\d+)
```

Compared to the method described in the other post, I dropped the look-ahead, since in this case, we don't need to check against a suffix.

The separator here is `(?>\s+and\s+|[\s,]+)`. It currently allows "and" with spaces on both sides, or any mix of spaces and commas. I use `(?>pattern)` to inhibit backtracking, so the order of the alternation is significant. Change it back to `(?:pattern)` if you want to modify it and you are unsure of what you are doing.

Sample code:

```
String input = "some text key 12, 32, 311 ,465 and 345. some other text dog 612,\n12, 32, 9 and 10. some text key 1, 2. key 1, 2 dog 3, 4 key 5, 6. key is dog 23, 45. key 4";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:key(?>\\s+and\\s+|[\\s,]+)|(?!^)\\G(?>\\s+and\\s+|[\\s,]+))(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

while (m.find()) {
    numbers.add(m.group(1));
}

System.out.println(numbers);
```

[**Demo on ideone**](http://ideone.com/OFLEg7)

Comment: This is really the correct regex +1. Was going to post similar but dropped due to loose nature of input data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive look behind which ensure that your sequence doesn't precede by any word except `key` :

```
(?<=key)\s(?:\d+[\s,]+)+(?:and )?\d+
```

Note that here you don't need to use a negative look behind for `dog` because this regex will just match if your sequence precede by `key`.

See demo https://regex101.com/r/gZ4hS4/3

Comment: In the last it should be \d+, otherwise it would not match two digit number and higher in last.

Comment: @Rahul Actually after `and` we write one digit! but its better to use `\d+`!

Comment: it will not match completly if you use only \d in `some text key 12, 32, 311 ,465 and 345. some other text dog 612, 
12, 32, 9 and 10. some text`

Comment: Now your regex is good but earlier you used `(?<=key)[^\d]*[\d, ]+(?:and )?\d`.

Comment: @Kasramvd i'm looking for individual set of results rather than 1 single result. is it possible?

Comment: @GilPeretz Do you mean the word `key` can be various?

Comment: @Kasramvd I mean that the `key` word can appear multiple times and the `dog` word can appear multiple time as well (without any particular order)

Comment: @GilPeretz Yep, fixed!

Comment: @nhahtdh Yep, I think there is no need to `[^\d]*` here! because the numbers should come right after the `key`!