# Regex - Inserting a character between all repetitions of 2 tags

Tags: regex, replace, repeat

I'm struggling to separate an unknown number of repetitions of "`<a></a><a></a>...`" by "`<a></a>::<a></a>...`", C++ namespace style.

My 2 problems:

1. I think I'm going to have to use the G modifier but I want this replacement limited to a certain div (class="namespace") and nowhere else (look behind?)
2. The main problem is the unknown number of groups in the matched expression. It's not like I can go \1::\2::\3::... so I think I'm missing a regex technique here, or is it just impossible?

A sample of my file and my regexp is [available here](https://regex101.com/r/oD7kF7/1).

Thank you so much for enlightening me !

Comment: What is the language/tool you are using?

Comment: I'm working in an Ant script.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can do this in an Ant script, but you might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268504/collapse-and-capture-a-repeating-pattern-in-a-single-regex-expression/15418942#15418942 That's the only way to construct a regex to do this when you don't have a programming language to script.